# JQuery JSON call returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a local webserver running on port 4444.
This webserver serves html pages and other files, which is going fine. However when I try to get JSON data from the server, I get a timeout with the error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in the Javascript console. If I load the JSON as a page, it shows correctly.

I tested with Chrome and Firefox. Both don't show any error other than timeout and ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome.

- It could be that the JSON is wrongly formatted.
- There could be another issue related to domains (I figure since I'm hosting locally).
- Or my HTTP headers are wrong.

This is my JSON data.

```
[
{
"x": "286.610989010989",
"y": "43.716483516483514",
"r": "103.5956043956044",
"g": "127.81208791208792",
"b": "143.07472527472527"
},
{
"x": "286.610989010989",
"y": "43.716483516483514",
"r": "103.5956043956044",
"g": "127.81208791208792",
"b": "143.07472527472527"
},
]
```

This is my ajax call. I tried also setting the content-type.

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/data", 
        type: "json",
        timeout: 3000, 
        success: actData,
        complete: getData,
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

These are my HTTP headers. I tried setting the content type to application/json and text/html.

```
    os.print("HTTP/1.0 200" + "\r\n");
    os.print("Content-Type: text/plain" + "\r\n");

    os.print("Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n");
    os.print("\r\n");
    os.write(data);
```

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that error means the browser received the file headers but the file content was empty. That would lead me to suspect that `data` had no value for some reason.

Comment: I can open /data in the browser and it always shows fine. I tried to prepend it with http:// host:4444, but that's not the problem apparently.

Comment: One last guess for you. Can you try commenting out the Content-Length line?

Comment: No dice, doesn't seem to change anything. I'm looking at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ as I think the fault is in the headers, because I'm using application/json.

Comment: Dang. Well hope you get it figured out.

Comment: I just did! Thanks for the help, it lead me to the right path!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, and it was sillier than I expected. I filtered my requests to allow only POST and GET, as I thought it is good behaviour to filter input. However, JSON requests actually send a header with JSON instead of GET. So it got filtered. Hence I could actually see it in the browser, but not retrieve it as JSON (as then it would send the JSON header).

Answer (score -3):

Your call ajax is incorrect,  the correct call is.

```
$.ajax({
    data:{myparam},
    type:get,
    datatype:json,
    URL:myurl,
    success:mifunction,
    error:myControl
});
```